# Internal laptop screen sometimes not detected at login with Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, screen

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on an Aero 15 OLED laptop. Everything was working fine until I updated the NVidia driver to 535.86.10.

##### The problem:

Sometimes (I would say roughly 70% of times), whenever I boot, the internal laptop display goes completely black (either immediately after the system loads, but before the login screen or immediately after logging in).

##### What I did so far:

1. Up until a few days ago, the only solution I found was to `REISUB` until I could boot and login (obviously not ideal).
2. If I choose the intel driver by doing `sudo prime-select intel`, I never encounter this issue.
3. A few days ago, I discovered that I can plug an external display (which does work). Using the external display I can access the Display Settings and see that actually my internal laptop screen *is* recognized (it just does not show any images). Moreover, I can play with the configuration. If I then do the following:

- select the external display as the only display (followed by accepting the settings).
- select both displays and accept the settings.

By doing these two steps, I can revive my laptop screen.

Obviously, all this is suboptimal... I would like to diagnose and solve the problem.

In an attempt to diagnose the problem myself, I looked at the `/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log` file, but I do not know exactly what to look for.